# Where to make feature-requests for the API?

Tags: discussion, support, api

I'm making an iOS app that uses the SE API. I have a few feature-requests for the API itself -  such as this:

> Give me a list of *unread* (those highlighted in the rep view) rep changes.

and

> Allow me to mark inbox messages a read through the API

Etc.

Where should I make these requests? Here? Stack Apps?

Comment: I'd say here. StackApps is for apps **using** the API.

Comment: Please use [tag:feature-request] also. Just want to see 3 of 4 required tags in the same post ^_^

Comment: To my recollection, there is no designated meta for StackApps; that is to say, _this_ is SA's meta

Comment: @juergend Actually, now that I actually read the [about](http://stackapps.com/about), it seems to say this: How do I use this site? ... **- Propose new features for the API**

Comment: Maybe I should start reading things.

Comment: @hjp [Hmmm? :)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+bug+support)

Comment: @Emrakul No, Stack Apps is its own meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should request changes to – as well as bugs in – the API on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com). It has comparable [feature request](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/bug), and [support](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/support) tags for this purpose.

[Kevin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose)'s pretty good about monitoring activity there, although feature requests will almost always be delayed until a new release of the API, provided that they're even something the team feels should be included. As a result you may not always get official feedback on feature requests right away.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/4257/give-us-a-sites-api-name-in-the-list-of-a-users-sites